# Pycharm not running Anaconda environment

Tags: pycharm, anaconda

I´m using an Anaconda environment with Pandas, Tensorflow, Keras and Matplotlib.

When I run a code in the Anaconda Prompt it works preftly, but when I try to run it in Pycharm I get an error message saying it can´t find the dependencies.

**The error message**

```
 File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Lia love/TestAi/Test1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 20, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\scikit_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

I selected the same environmet as the project interpreter in Pycharm. I see the required packages in the list.

I don´t understand what I´m missing here.

Project´s interpreter packages

```
Keras   2.2.4   2.2.4
Keras-Applications  1.0.7   1.0.7
Keras-Preprocessing 1.0.9   1.0.9
Markdown    3.1 3.1.1
PyYAML  5.1 5.1
Werkzeug    0.15.2  0.15.4
absl-py 0.7.1   0.7.1
astor   0.7.1   0.8.0
certifi 2019.3.9    2019.3.9
cycler  0.10.0  0.10.0
gast    0.2.2   0.2.2
grpcio  1.16.1  1.21.1
h5py    2.9.0   2.9.0
joblib  0.13.2  0.13.2
kiwisolver  1.1.0   1.1.0
matplotlib  3.0.3   3.1.0
mkl-fft 1.0.12  1.0.6
mkl-random  1.0.2   1.0.1.1
mock    2.0.0   3.0.5
numpy   1.16.3  1.16.3
pandas  0.24.2  0.24.2
pbr 5.1.3   5.2.0
pip 19.1.1  19.1.1
protobuf    3.7.1   3.7.1
pyparsing   2.4.0   2.4.0
pyreadline  2.1 2.1
python-dateutil 2.8.0   2.8.0
pytz    2019.1  2019.1
scikit-learn    0.21.1  0.21.2
scipy   1.2.1   1.3.0
setuptools  41.0.1  41.0.1
six 1.12.0  1.12.0
tensorboard 1.13.1  1.13.1
tensorflow  1.13.1  1.13.1
tensorflow-estimator    1.13.0  1.13.0
termcolor   1.1.0   1.1.0
tornado 6.0.2   6.0.2
wheel   0.33.4  0.33.4
wincertstore    0.2 0.2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe upload a screenshot of your project settings -> Project Interpreter?

Comment: @ReineFang Just updated the post with the list of packages in the environment

Comment: Perhaps try this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/managing-dependencies.html? I haven't used PyCharm in awhile but I vaguely remember that sometimes version incompatibility can cause issues too, not sure if this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the latest [2019.1.3 RC build](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=23004355). It contains a bunch of relevant fixes for Anaconda support in PyCharm (e.g. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35141). The problem with "Missing required dependencies" should be addressed there as well.